# Scroll to div on clicking the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/hitech0101/5vhdm5hy/

```
$('.block').click( function () {
    $('#mainContainer').animate({'width':'20%'}, 1000);
  $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'});
  $('.block').css({'display':'block','width':'100%'});
  $('.second').css({'display':'inline-block'})
    });
```

In the fiddle, i am using jquery to convert the horizontal blocks into vertical blocks. I have changed the block color from red to blue when the block is clicked. When i click a particular block i would the scroll to move to the location of the block in the vertical view. I have tried jquery's scrollTop() method but still could not get it working the way i wanted it to. Please help.

The fiddle is partial representation of the webpage i am working on. There is more content on the original page which i have excluded. The maincontainer is the second container on the page.

Comment: Edited fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Add this line into the `.click` function.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vhdm5hy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript necessary. You can specify an element in an anchor's `href` and it'll scroll it to the top of the window, including itself.

Wrap the `div` in an anchor or just use the anchor tag itself, they're both wrappers.

```
<a href="#scrollToMe">
  <div id="scrollToMe"></div>
</a>
```

Just remember that it can only scroll the element into view to the best of its ability, if the item is at the bottom of the parent element the scroll will hit the bottom and it won't be able to go any further.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get the offset top value and animate the #maincontainer to that position

```
$('.block').click( function () {
    $('#mainContainer').animate({'width':'20%'}, 1000);
    $(this).css({'background-color':'blue'});
    $('.block').css({'display':'block','width':'100%'});
    $('.second').css({'display':'inline-block'});
    /*below is what i was talking about*/
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    $('#mainContainer').animate({ scrollTop: pos.top });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".block", function() {
    var _body_html = $('html, body');
    var _scroll_to = $('.scroll-to');
    var _top = _scroll_to.offset().top;
    _body_html.animate({
        scrollTop: _top
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        _body_html.finish();
    }, 1000);
});
```